# Removing Class with Mouse Exit

Tags: jquery, mouseleave

I am performing a on mouseenter / mouseleave with jQuery and it appears to be working but not when I exit the div. This is only working when I exit the actual window.

This is my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".pods .col").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).find(".pod-overlay").addClass("show")
  });
  $(".pods .col").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).find(".pod-overlay").removeClass("show")
  });
});
```

This is my HTML

```
<div id="splash" class="section section-splash bg">
  <div class="pods">
    <div class="col col-4">
      <div id="pod-splash-food" class="pod pod-food">
        <div class="pod-overlay"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have done a js fiddle here. I am learning jquery, so advice is appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/34h48148/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function works perfect! The problem is the overlay. You place that absolute, making it cover the whole body. So, change your CSS a bit, place `.pods` and `.col` relative.

```
.pods,.col { overflow: auto; position: relative; }
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/34h48148/6/)

The only thing I would change on your function, is binding both events on the same caller:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".pods .col").on("mouseenter", function() {
        $(this).find(".pod-overlay").addClass("show")
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
        $(this).find(".pod-overlay").removeClass("show")
    });
});
```

Comment: Haha - Kirsty has accepted almost all the answers in turn today

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `hover` event like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".pods .col").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".pod-overlay").addClass("show")
  }, function() {
    $(this).find(".pod-overlay").removeClass("show")
  });
});
```

And this is the [hover event doc](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

---

However, the problem is not the function but the CSS associated to the `pod-overlay` class.

Add these two attributes in your css :

```
.pod-overlay {
    width:260px;
    height:260px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: @mplungjan This will work now. The real problem is from the `width` & `height` of the overlay, and not from the function (his function was working). Btw, your function didn't work either :3

Comment: I was using .on("hover") !

Answer (score 4):

Your method is fine but you it doesn't work on mouseleave is because the overlay is on top of `.col` and hence mouseleave is never triggered. You can use [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) as well apart from what the other answers suggest. Something like this

```
.pod-overlay {
    pointer-events: none;
    ....
}
```

Here is the updated demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/34h48148/9/**

PS: I changed the border of overlay only to show the overlay boundaries.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use pure css

```
.pods .col:hover .pod-overlay{
    visibility: visible;
}

.pods .col .pod-overlay{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hey Hacketo, http://www.asda.com/summer/index.html I was trying to recreate this, hence the jquery :)

Comment: @KirstyMarks this can be done with pure css, but it seem they use javascript to do it

Answer (score 1):

Actualy, the code is working, the problem is that you set the even on the ".pods" class which cover the whole page... So the even is only triggered when you mouse out of the page

Answer (score 1):

> learning jquery, so advice is appreciated.

jQuery not needed to achieve requirement. Try utilizing `css` pseudo class `:hover`

```css
.pod {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}
.pod-overlay {
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9)
}

.pods .col:hover .pod-overlay  {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="splash" class="section section-splash bg">
    <div class="pods">
        <div class="col col-4">
            <div id="pod-splash-food" class="pod pod-food">
                <div class="pod-overlay"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/34h48148/11/

Answer (score 0):

The actual mouse event you should be calling is **onmouseout**

```
$(".pods .col").on("mouseout", function() {
  $(this).find(".pod-overlay").removeClass("show")
});
```